# Correct use and update of GCM-Ids

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a question about the correct use of `GCM-IDs`.

At the moment I have a `InstanceIDListenerService` a `GcmListenerService` and a `RegestrationIntentService`.

The `RegeistrationIntentServie` get started in the `MainActivity` every time someone opens the app.

I think this is a correct implementation of the Google guidelines.

But what is the best way to handle the `GCM-ID` so that I will not have incorrect `GCM-IDs` on my server after the refresh in the `InstandeIDListenerService`. Because at the moment the refresh only registers a new `GCM-ID` on my server.

Would it be an idea to generate a random Device ID so that I can update the old `GCM-ID`?

How do you handle the IDs?

Because at the moment I ask the server every start of the app if he knows a `GCM-ID` in combination with a (randomly generated) Device-ID and update one of both if the other one is incorrect or does not exist.

And I think that produces a lot of network traffic for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, you are not calling `InstanceIDListenerService.onTokenRefresh()` yourself right? This will be called by the system if necessary.

To answer your question, you should use the GCM functionality called "canonical IDs":

> **[Canonical IDs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids)**
>
> **If a bug in the client app triggers multiple registrations for the
>   same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and the client app
>   might end up with duplicate messages.**
>
> Implementing canonical IDs can help you more easily recover from these
>   situations. **A canonical registration ID is the registration token of
>   the last registration requested by the client app. This is the ID
>   that the server should use when sending messages to the device.**
>
> If you try to send a message using an old registration token, GCM will
>   process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical ID in
>   the registration_id field of the response. **Make sure to replace the
>   registration token stored in your server with this canonical ID, as
>   eventually the old registration token will stop working.**

To be more precise, if there are two registrations for the same device and you send a notification using the older registration ID, you will get the canonical ID (the registration ID of the newest registration for this device). If this ID is already stored on your server, delete the old registration. If the canonical ID is not stored on your server for any reason, replace the registration ID you used to send the notification with the canonical ID.

Comment: Yes I do not call the InstanceIDListenerService.onTokenRefresh() by myself! But I think that the system calls it sometimes. Do you know when?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService.html#onTokenRefresh()) just states "_Called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed. The application should call getToken() and send the tokens to all application servers. This will not be called very frequently, it is needed for key rotation and to handle special cases._"

Answer (score 0):

@leet GCM ID token initiates callback periodically when your token needs to be refresh, or sometime when:
-   Security issues; like ssl or platform issues
-   Device info is no longer valid; for example backup and restore.
-   Instance ID service is otherwise affected.

```
public class MyInstanceIDService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
 public void onTokenRefresh() {
    refreshAllTokens();
}
private void refreshAllTokens() {
 // assuming you have defined TokenList as
 // some generalized store for your tokens
 ArrayList<TokenList> tokenList = TokensList.get();
 InstanceID iid = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
 for(tokenItem : tokenList) {
 tokenItem.token =
 iid.getToken(tokenItem.authorizedEntity,tokenItem.scope,tokenItem.options);
 // send this tokenItem.token to your server
 }
 }
};
```

> [**Keeping the Registration State in
>   Sync**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#keeping-the-registration-state-in-sync)
>
> To protect the client app and app server from potential malicious
>   re-use of registration tokens, you should periodically initiate token
>   refresh from the server. When GCM registration token refresh is
>   initiated from server side, the client app must handle
>   a tokenRefreshed message with the GCM registration client/server
>   handshake. This [link](https://developers.) may help you verify on how
>   to handle Refresh Token.

As Baris have metioned, your server must use canonical IDs when you are sending message to the device. The tokenRefresh would remove the idea of generating  a random device ID and Canonical IDs would solve on how you verify if the ID is correct or not.